# Python 2.x: Summing items in a list of tuples

Tags: list, python-2.7, indexing, tuples, slice

For summation purposes, I created a list of tuples, where multiple items in the list have the same first variable. 
for example:

```
    x = [('m32',[1,2,3]),('m32',[2,3,4]),('m32',[4,5,6]),('m33',[1,2,3]),('m33',[2,3,4]),('m33',[4,5,6]),('m34',[1,2,3]),('m34',[2,3,4]),('m34',[4,5,6])....]
```

I want to add the individual values of the second items in the tuples (i.e 1+2+4, 2+3+5, 3+4+6) for all values that have the same first item (i.e. 'm32').

In other words, for all items labeled 'm32', I want to be able to add the other values.

How can I slice/index this to loop through and perform the summation?

Comment: You should accept an answer by clicking on the "arrow", that will remove the question from the "un-answered questions list"

Answer (score 0):

Some tricky `zip` magic, along with `itertools.groupby` to group the matching first items together:

```
>>> x = [('m32',[1,2,3]),('m32',[2,3,4]),('m32',[4,5,6]),('m33',[1,2,3]),('m33',[2,3,4]),('m33',[4,5,6]),('m34',[1,2,3]),('m34',[2,3,4]),('m34',[4,5,6])]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> for k,g in groupby(x,key=itemgetter(0)):
...  print (k,[sum(i) for i in zip(*zip(*g)[1])])
...
('m32', [7, 10, 13])
('m33', [7, 10, 13])
('m34', [7, 10, 13])
```

A breakdown of how it works:

`g` is the group of items with matching keys.  `zip(*g)` transposes the matrix, bringing the keys and values together:

```
>>> for k,g in groupby(x,key=itemgetter(0)):
...  print zip(*g)
...
[('m32', 'm32', 'm32'), ([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6])]
[('m33', 'm33', 'm33'), ([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6])]
[('m34', 'm34', 'm34'), ([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6])]
```

Getting the 2nd items:

```
>>> for k,g in groupby(x,key=itemgetter(0)):
...  print zip(*g)[1]
...
([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6])
([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6])
([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6])
```

Transposing again to match up the items to sum:

```
>>> for k,g in groupby(x,key=itemgetter(0)):
...  print zip(*zip(*g)[1])
...
[(1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 5), (3, 4, 6)]
[(1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 5), (3, 4, 6)]
[(1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 5), (3, 4, 6)]
```

And adding them up:

```
>>> for k,g in groupby(x,key=itemgetter(0)):
...  print [sum(i) for i in zip(*zip(*g)[1])]
...
[7, 10, 13]
[7, 10, 13]
[7, 10, 13]
```

Comment: This is awesome! But, as rsm pointed out, even with an explanation, this is a bit beyond me and my level of understanding. Thanks, and I hope someone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Mark is great, and probably much more efficient that the one I'll post you. But I still want to post my answer because you are probably new to python and it will be easy for you to understand it.

For this kind of scripts you only need some imagination and basic python notions:

```
dictionary={}
for name, numbers in x:
    if name in dictionary:
        current_list=dictionary[name]

        for i in range(3):
            current_list[i]+=numbers[i]

    else:
        dictionary[name]=numbers

print(dictionary)
```

Note that the output is a dictionary:
`{'m32': [7, 10, 13], 'm33': [7, 10, 13]}`..

I hope it help you!

Comment: You're right, this is more along what I am looking for. Is there a way to do this without creating a dictionary? I need to loop through the "keys" later for a formatted output. or can you do "for keys in dictionary:...." kind of thing?

Comment: would it be easier if used a list of lists, or didnt put the tuples in a list to begin with?

Comment: @catalyst123 using a dict is really usefull, you can directly get its values, or keys for example `for key in dictionary.keys()`, or directly get the lists `for value in dictonary.values()` or even get both `for key, value in dictonary.items()`